# Need this disable enter function in Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

Can someone please convert this native JS function into Mootools for me?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function stopRKey(evt) {
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;}
}

document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
</script>
```

Thanks a lot,
Torsten

Comment: Torten, can you explain more what you are trying to do? where does the `event` variable from your code come from?

Comment: Hi Sergio, Thanks for helping! This script is to disable the default enter button behaviour so a form cannot be submitted by pressing the enter button by mistake. "Event" is a JS object actually. The variable here is evt.

Comment: So you want a form to only submit on `click` ? some people do surf only with keys so that would limit them. You could have a confirmation question instead? Are you submitting by ajax or posting the page? And, also, please share some HTML so its more clear what you have.

Comment: Torsten, if you make more detailed questions you will get more detailed andwers. Guessing what you might need I made this: __http://jsfiddle.net/dSht9/__ Is that what you wanted?

Comment: this is so broken on many levels. `input[type=email],input[type=password]` etc all new HTML5 inputs will fail. also, attaching the event as low in the DOM tree as `document` is an anti-pattern that can be expensive due to bubbling. consider a simpler http://jsfiddle.net/dSht9/2/ - it binds around a particular form element, it only fires the event when the tag is matched and stops it via the mootools API (does `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`). adding random document keystroke handlers is a huge no-go. keep it simple, keep it isolated. don't pollute global object needlessly

Comment: I would follow Dimitar's advise here.